# Stream windows screen-capture

Tags: windows, streaming

Is there any way to constantly capture windows screen (like they do in remote desktop) and stream it on a server so that i can read it on my android device ?

Comment: Can you explain your requirements more specifically? Based on the current information I would suggest a remote connection via VNC/RDP, but that may not be what you want (from your "like they do in remote dekstop" comment)

Comment: VNC is efficient for what you want. Most servers allow you to run a view-only mode which are just like stream screen captures. If you want control, then RDP is better experience.